# Spotify no longer responding to media keys in windows 10 since I installed youtube music

Tags: windows-10, spotify, media-keys

I used to be able to control Spotify using media keys on my keyboard and headset on my Windows 10 machine. This worked and I was happy.

At some point I wanted to try Youtube Music and I installed the Youtube Music desktop app from https://ytmdesktop.app/. I was able to control the Youtube Music desktop app using the media keys on my keyboard and headset. I tried Youtube music for a short while and came to the conclusion that it is way worse then Spotify (really don't bother, it's unusable). So I uninstalled the YTM desktop app.

Now I'm back to Spotify but my media keys are not working anymore for it.

I have the Chrome flag Hardware Media Key Handling set to disabled. So that should not be the problem.

I tried reïnstalling spotify, but it didn't work.

I tried searching online but the only answer I can ever find is disabling the Chrome flag. This doesn't work for me.

Even when Spotify is the only app running it will still not respond to media key input.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? Is there a way to check which app has taken control of the media keys? Could it be that YTM Desktop app made some kind of registry edit so no other media player can use the media keys ever again? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would suggest: (1) Install Youtube Music, (2) Uninstall it using [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/), (3) Uninstall Spotify using Revo, (4) Install Spotify.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look into it. I don't know Revo, what does it do?

Comment: Revo is an uninstaller that cleans up left-over file & registry, so it does a clean uninstall.

Comment: tried this, but it didn't help. Good suggestion though.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. If all this happened recently enough and System Restore is enabled, you could rollback Windows to a time when everything worked well. If you have installed or uninstalled other apps in that period, there might be a problem.

Comment: Yes this has been a while ago and I have installed a lot of things in the mean time. Its a work PC so I'm not sure I'm allowed to do a System Restore.

Comment: @harrymc In Revo I ran the moderate scan. Would an advanced scan be more thorough?

Comment: Yes, advanced scan would be more thorough.

Comment: I do not know why but a Windows update has fixed this issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a Windows Update has fixed this problem, so impossible to know what was its cause.

Comment: Is closing a question a thing on stack exchange?

Comment: It's done when a question cannot have an answer or doesn't fit in.